# kendo ui: create flowchart with diagram widget?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, diagram, flowchart

I am looking into the Kendo UI diagram tool and am surprised to see **no** examples of a traditional **flowchart** or workflow diagram. All the examples seem to be iterations of an org chart, with shapes of either circles or rectangles.

- http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/diagram/index

Is it possible to build a flowchart with the traditional shapes a flowchart uses for steps in a process using Kendo UI?

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart

---

[image]

http://flowchart.js.org/

---

Other examples via google images:
https://www.google.com/search?q=flowchart+diagram&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjggcL226bTAhWm8YMKHXjFAGgQ_AUICCgB&biw=1560&bih=947#imgrc=-FRG6V34Y42ByM:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to build a flowchart diagram with the Kendo UI diagram tool.

The reason I came to this conclusion is because of a book published in 2014 called **[Kendo UI Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781783980000.do)** which includes a walkthrough of a very simple flowchart.

It appears only rectangle and circle shapes are part of the core Shapes for the diagram tool, you probably have to acquire other SVG paths to plug in to the Kendo UI api and visualize other traditional shapes found in workflow/visio-style diagrams.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/diagram#configuration-shapeDefaults.type

`<aside mode="flustered">`
I am perplexed as to why Progress/Telerik/Kendo UI has not - as of this date - included a flowchart diagram in their code demos for their diagram tool? No doubt there are others out there who are looking **specifically for this feature**, and if Kendo UI does not make it clear they include the feature, but another javascript components vendor does in their demo samples, then the case for purchasing Kendo UI is not so good. Kendo UI - please put a demo for a flowchart on your site; it is going to help people who might buy your product and probably help you sell your product.
`</aside>`